# Android MapView getlongitude and getlatitude returns 0.0 on volley request

Tags: android, gps, fragment, android-volley, android-mapview

Hello I have a problem about the Location get longitude and get latitude.
It is always 0.0 on my database.

It uses volley to pass the the lngs and lats variable but when it arrive the value is 0.0

The variables lats and lngs should have been updated in the onLocationChanged() function

Here is some of my code

```
Private double lats;
Private double lngs;

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View myinflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    final TextView usr = (TextView)myinflate.findViewById(R.id.user);



    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    usrnme = extras.getString("user");


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);

    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            lats=location.getLatitude();
            lngs=location.getLongitude();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),PERMISSIONS_LOCATION,REQUEST_LOCATION);

        }

    }
    else
    {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
    }





            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("usr", usrnme);
                    parameters.put("lat", Double.toString(lats));
                    parameters.put("lng", Double.toString(lngs));

                    return parameters;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're handing over the lats and longs to server a bit earlier. Instead, send the location right after you have the onLocationChanged method called from locationManager listener.

```
Private double lats;
Private double lngs;

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View myinflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    final TextView usr = (TextView)myinflate.findViewById(R.id.user);



    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    usrnme = extras.getString("user");


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);

    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            lats=location.getLatitude();
            lngs=location.getLongitude();

            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("usr", usrnme);
                    parameters.put("lat", Double.toString(lats));
                    parameters.put("lng", Double.toString(lngs));

                    return parameters;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),PERMISSIONS_LOCATION,REQUEST_LOCATION);

        }

    }
    else
    {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! The lats and lngs are now in my database! however when i tried to use the lats and lngs variable in my marker in the map it sends me to Africa! lol which is not equal to the same lats and lngs variable that was sent.. any ideas?

Comment: From `onLocationChanged`, can you put a Log on lats and lngs values and then put the value at www.maps.google.com to see where it actually leads? If it still leads you to Africa then the location you're getting from server is truly given by your app.

Comment: this is strange, when i log the values of lat and lngs inside the onLocationChanged the values are right but when i log the values outside in the marker area the values are 0.0 and 0.0 although lat and lngs are declared at the very top so the lat and lngs values should have changed right but why it returns 0 ? really strange

Comment: This is asynchronous behavior. The onLocationChanged method get called after it get the location. It usually takes a couple milliseconds. Now, if you Log the lat long values outside of the listener then, compiler will execute that line immediately. So, it gets the blank values.

Comment: I see.. how do i get to use or can i use the lats and lngs values outside of the onLocationChanged? Because i want to plot marker using those values but sadly the values are 0.0                                                                 MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(lats, lngs)).title("Hello!");

Comment: Pass the updated location values from onLocationChanged method to your marker. This will let your marker to have the updated location. If you just put the marker code outside of the listener then you're using the declared value of your lat long.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping! Can i have a last question please? How do i pass the lats and lngs from onLocationChanged method to my marker? thanks again!

Comment: Yes, sure. Create a method, say, `createMarker(double latVal, double longVal)` where you put in marker related codes. This method will take lat long values as method parameters. Now, simply call that method from your onLocationChanged method with your updated lats and lng variables like this,

`public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            lats=location.getLatitude();
            lngs=location.getLongitude();

createMarker(lats, lngs);

// other code

`